# Why does Ruby `**` operator have higher precedence than unary `-`?

Tags: ruby, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

This leads to the situation like:

```
-1 ** 0.5 #=> -1
```

Only parenthesis remedies it:

```
(-1) ** 0.5 #=> 6.123031769111886e-17+1.0i
```

which is less favorable then expected `1.i`, but basically acceptable. Before I go to Ruby bugs to complain, I would like to know whether there is perhaps some reason for this to be so?

Comment: I'm observing the same with Python. I don't know about other programming languages, but it doesn't seem to be Ruby-specific.

Comment: But it's insane, or is it just me?

Comment: Interestingly enough, it *is*  a special case mentioned explicitly [in the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#id28): unary `-` does have higher precedence than `**` on the RHS only.

Comment: Interesting. So at least Python devs seem to agree with me on this one issue.

Comment: Well, but only because there's no other way to parse `0.5 ** -1`.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: It is higher when the unary `-` is the power, not the base. There isn't any other way of interpreting it.

Comment: :-( that one works in Ruby, too: `0.5 ** -1 #=> 2`, as expected. But I'd really like it to bind more tightly on the LHS, too...

Comment: I've created [a Ruby issue for this](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7328). Let's see what they say when rejecting it.

Comment: I think whichever way you cut it, someone will be surprised it wasn't the other way around

Comment: That is the way it is in mathematics.

Comment: @sawa: You mean like `-n²`? But that looks totally different than `-2 ** 2`.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky That is what it is. Knuth notation for power is to use either `↑` or `^` instead of superscript: `-n^2`. In programming, this power `^` is expressed as `**`. In all the notational variants, the strength of the associativity is the same.

Comment: @sawa: Thanks, Matz rationalized the `**` precedence in the same way (mathematics). This behavior goes against mine and many others' intuition, but as long as it is wanted and rationalized, I am satisfied and can simply memorize it for use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many languages define their operator precedence tables by modeling after mathematics' order of operations. In math, exponentiation does have higher precedence than multiplication, and unary negation *is* a multiplication, after all.

From matz in a [reply](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/87126#163398) to "the sign of a number is omitted when squaring it":

> People with mathematical background demands precedence for ** being
>   higher than that of unary minus.  That's the reason.

Comment: I apologize, but I cannot agree with this rationalization. I would accept it if you provide a link to where Matz says so. Multiplication in the strict sense is defined by '*'. Unary '-' is negation, distinct from both multiplication and subtraction.

Comment: Also, from the algebra point of view, negation does not even require multiplication to be defined. It simply requires that addition is defined, and that a + negated_a = 0.

Comment: If Ruby would have been modelled after math it would have been the other way around. Today, "-1 squared" (-1 ** 2) yields -1, not 1 which is the natural mathematical result, as Ruby parses this "-(1 squared)".

Comment: @pst: Thanks for the link, that's what I was after.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `**` has a [higher precedence](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4) in Ruby.

Unlike some languages, `-` is *not* lex'ed as part of the number literal and is thus just (and universally) the unary `-` (aka `-@`). That is, both `-x` and `-1` parse the unary `-@` as an operator applied to the result of the expression.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I already knew that. I am having problem with `**` having higher binding force (ie. precedence) than `-@`, and I am asking whether this has been rationalized by Matz somewhere, or I am free to complain about it.

Comment: Let's wait whether anyone knows anything more on this.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I updated Platinum's answer with the forum link he found. I think that answers the "why" bit from Matz's view.